# JSF with gettable only

Tags: java, jsf-2

I'm trying to achieve a chat system through JSF. All text typed inside `h:inputText` will be stored after `h:commandButton` is pressed. After this, I have a table to print all data typed so far. This way, I have the following code for JSF:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText id="id1" value="#{unicoBean.text}" />
    <h:commandButton id="botao" value="Entrar" action="#{unicoBean.test}"
        onclick="test()"
    />
</h:form>
<h:dataTable value="#{unicoBean.all}" var="msg">
    <h:column>
    #{msg.text}
</h:column>
</h:dataTable>
<script>
    function test() {
        alert("alert");
    }
</script>
```

And this for backbean:

```
@ManagedBean
public class UnicoBean {
Facade f = new Facade();

public void setText(String s) throws Exception {
    f.setText(s);
    }

public List<Message> getAll() throws Exception {
    return f.getAll();
    }

public void test() {
    System.out.println("bean called on jsf");
    }
}
```

Inside h:inputText I want only to set values, not get them and throw back to html. Unfortunately, JSF says "Expression is not gettable", even when I don't want to get anything, only set, as exposed on my Bean. How I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to achieve this using getter/setter strategy because is not part of JSF but Expression Language (EL). JSF only uses it to bind the data of the HTML components to the fields of a bean through proper getters and setters

However, you can use `binding` attribute via [UIInput](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html) to pass the input field value as an argument to your action button:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText id="id1" binding="#{input1}" />
    <h:commandButton id="botao" value="Entrar" action="#{unicoBean.test(input1.value)}"
        onclick="test()" />
</h:form>
```

And then receive the new value from your action method:

```
public void test(String value) {
    System.out.println("bean called on jsf: " + value);
}
```